# LDAP query return empty result when I have many groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap-query

I generated the following ldap query:

```
(&(objectcategory=group)(|(name=g1)(name=g2) (name=g3)…(name=g20000)))
```

But received empty result. When I changed the query to look for only 5,000 groups instead of 20,000 It worked:

```
(&(objectcategory=group)(|(name=g1)(name=g2) (name=g3)…(name=g5000)))
```

Any ideas why? Is it because the query string was too long? or that the result was too big?
Is there a setting that I can change in the active directory to fix that?

Comment: What tool is used to retrieve groups? Is it aduc (active directory users and computers)?

Comment: I implemented my own client using JAVA/C# to connect to the active directory and then executed the LDAP search query. I tried also with aduc (active directory users and computers), but it didn't let me entering such a long string as input.

Comment: The filter string is to big. Split you filter and make multiple requests or use wildcards if all the groups in case have the same name pattern

Comment: @oldovets thanks for you reply. Do you have a reference to support it? On one active directory it worked for me also with 20,000 and with another one it didn't.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755809(v=ws.10).aspx. See default values for ldap administrative limits. These values can be changed on domain controller